# html filter only one table on a page with multiple tables

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm writing a simple html page containing multiple table

```
<table class="tosearch">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Above each table I've placed an input text box

```
<input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for data...">
```

to filter the table's data with the following Js script (credits to chatgpt)

```
// script.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");

    // Get all tables in the document
    const tablesToSearch = document.querySelectorAll(".tosearch");

    // Event listener for search input
    searchInput.addEventListener("input", function () {
        const filter = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();

        // Filter all tables
        tablesToSearch.forEach(function (table) {
            filterTable(table, filter);
        });
    });

    function filterTable(table, filter) {
        const rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            const row = rows[i];
            const cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
            let shouldShow = false;

            for (let j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                const cell = cells[j];
                const text = cell.textContent.toLowerCase();

                if (text.includes(filter)) {
                    shouldShow = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            row.style.display = shouldShow ? "" : "none";
        }
    }
});
```

Everything works nice, but if I would like to have multiple tables on the same page, each with a text input above it.
If I just copy and paste the html code for the text input and the table, when I try to search the script filter on all tables, while I would like to filter only on the associated table, something like

```
textInput for table1 only
table1

textInput  for table2 only
table2
.
.
.
```

I hope I explained myself good enough, otherwise I'll make some edits.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? Why not use multiple pairs of input fields and tables?

Comment: I would like to know how to implement this

Comment: Take your code, turn it into a function that takes a table and an input, and then call that with each table input combo you want?

Comment: @somethinghere yeah that would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way was to make it a reusable function:

```js
function filterTable(table, filter) {

    const rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        const row = rows[i];
        const cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
        let shouldShow = false;

        for (let j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            const cell = cells[j];
            const text = cell.textContent.toLowerCase();

            if (text.includes(filter)) {
                shouldShow = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        row.style.display = shouldShow ? "" : "none";
    }
    
}

/* This method is called onload now, but is limited to arguments you have passed in.*/

function linkInputToTablesSearch( searchInput, tablesToSearch ){

    searchInput.addEventListener("input", function () {
    
        const filter = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();

        tablesToSearch.forEach(function (table) {
            filterTable(table, filter);
        });
        
    });
    
};


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

  document.querySelectorAll( 'input' ).forEach(input => {
      
    linkInputToTablesSearch( input, [ input.nextElementSibling ] );
    
  });

});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search for data...">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>a4</td>
      <td>a5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>b2</td>
      <td>b3</td>
      <td>b4</td>
      <td>b5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can now link the table and the input by calling `linkInputToTablesSearch` with the input and an array of tables as the arguments.

But your filtering has a couple of issues, the `break` is stopping it and you will never be able to hide rows after a match. I have a more simplified version of the filter here:

```js
function filterTable( table, query ){

  const regex = query && new RegExp( query, 'gi' );
    
  [...table.querySelectorAll( 'tr' )].forEach(row => {
    
    // Since you are filtering the rows, maybe skip the step of checking every cell individually. Although this would allow it to bleed (so if cell 1 contains a, and cell 2 contains b, the row contains the string 'ab'). If you want to avoid that, just filter through the cells here with the same regex.
    row.hidden = !!query && !regex.test( row.textContent );
      
  });
  
}
function linkInputToTables( input, tables ){
  
  // Ensure you have an array of tables. With this, you could also just pass in a single table selected with getElementById or querySelector
  tables = tables instanceof HTMLTableElement ? [ tables ] : tables;
  
  input.addEventListener( 'input', event => {
    
    tables.forEach(table => filterTable( table, input.value ));
    
  });
  
}

document.querySelectorAll( 'label' ).forEach(label => {
  
  const input = label.querySelector( 'input' );
  const target = document.querySelector( label.dataset.target );
  
  if( input && target ) linkInputToTables( input, target );
  
})
```

```css
#table1 { border: 3px solid red }
#table2 { border: 3px solid blue }
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>a4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td>b3</td>
    <td>b4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>a4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td>b3</td>
    <td>b4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<label data-target="#table1">
  <span>Just table 1</span>
  <input type="search" value="" id= />
</label>
<label data-target="#table2">
  <span>Just table 2</span>
  <input type="search" value="" id= />
</label>
```